# implementing inventory application in android with sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, inventory, mobile-application

I'm new to android and want to develop application to manage inventory on mobile.

I can run the application "Hello world" and can communicate with database as well.

But i'am having problem with navigation and forms and controls.

for my application i want to store the inventory data in database and retrieve in a grid format and managing the data.

can any one tell how to work this out please.

providing a tutorial is also acceptable (i tried some but not successful)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are stackoverflow experts outsourced to any other site?? No one to answer simple questions (for experts) on android??

Comment: Please ask only one question on a specific problem, not several.

Comment: @pentium10 thanks for the replay i'll remove my edit of the Question please answer my Question. Thanks.

Comment: @Pentium10 really cool website man like it. If you post as danswer i'll vote up for website and also for help :)

Answer (score 0):

srinivas.

Did you get it working?

You may be interested in this [inventory tutorial](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3). It uses Phonegap.

In addition it recommends the use of a free UPC Database found [here](http://www.upcdatabase.com/).